# Storing Business Logic Configuration in Azure

Tags: .net, azure

I am developing a .NET Web API application that will be hosted in Azure. The app required to read a json file, which contain tens of business rules (The file itself is less than 1MB) that the app dependent on to perform some business calculation.

The app itself does not require any storage as it performs a very specific function.

To my understanding, my options for storing this file are:

1. **Azure Storage/Database**  - Seems like an overkill, given that the file is less than 1MB and will never grow too much beyond that
2. **Part of the solution** - Deployed to Azure as part of the solution. Problem with this is that, whenever the business rules needs to be updated, it will require the whole solution to be deployed.
3. **Hard code the rules in the code** - Yuck, and it doesn't meet the business requirement

Is there any other option that I haven't come across?

Thank you!

Comment: azure blob storage is really cheap. you can use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the easiest way to store the json file is publish it as the part of the solution.

If you use azure storage/ database , you will need to get the file from blob or add a connection string to get the data from database.

As you says, it is overkill and will write more useless code to get data.

If you want to change the json file data, I suggest you could directly upload that json file by azure deployment like ftp,Kudu, web deploy.

More details, you could refer to follow link:

[Upload file by ftp](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftimagine/2015/12/22/microsoft-azure-tutorial-how-to-upload-a-website-to-the-cloud-via-ftp/)

[How to view, add, edit and remove files in Azure Web App using the Kudu service Dashboard](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/)

Comment: I didn't know you could upload files directly! Thank you!